# Адаптивный хедер с изменением структуры элементов?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Всем здравствуйте. У меня возникла задача, сделать хедер сайта адаптивным, но проблема в том, что в адаптиве сильно меняется структура элементов. Я начертила на картинке как есть на десктопе и как надо расположить элементы на версии для планшета. На данный момент я просто в коде скопировала блок с главным меню и отображаю его только на планшете, но беда в том, что в коде дважды одно и то же главное меню фигурирует и поисковые системы это не одобрят, а мне важно в поисковиках нормально сидеть. Можете предположить как бы вы решали эту задачу без дублирования кода?

[image: Схема расположения элементов]

Comment: Приветствую. На этом сайте помогают разобраться в какой-либо задаче, но никак не решить её за Вас. Выложите Ваши наработки и разберемся.

Comment: Почитайте про grid сетку. С помощью ее можно решить все без дублирования кода. [Статья на Хабре](https://habr.com/post/325760/)

Comment: Код моего хедера выложить? Я не прошу решить за меня, я попросила подсказать идеи как это можно было бы решить. сейчас я просто в коде сделала отдельный блок, в котором есть и главное меню и поиск внутри одной строки и вывожу его на планшетах, но в этой ситуации у меня дублируется код. Я хочу понимать есть ли возможно без дублирования кода обойтись.

Comment: Спасибо, о гридах думаю, но очень боюсь за те браузеры, которые грид не поддерживают, процент таковых еще достаточный.

Comment: По другому тут никак. Использовать JS чтобы переносить элементы еще хуже. Тут два варианта это дублирование кода, и второй это гриды.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю grid ...единственное средство которое манипулируется легко ...

```css
.item-a{background:red;}
.item-b{background:green;}
.item-c{background:blue;}
.item-d{background:yellow;}
.item-e{background:pink;}
.item-f{background:gray;}

.item-a{grid-area:a-side;  /*logo*/  }
.item-b{grid-area:b-side;  /*city*/  }
.item-c{grid-area:c-side;  /*phone*/ }
.item-d{grid-area:d-side;  /*search*/}
.item-e{grid-area:e-side;  /*basket*/}
.item-f{grid-area:f-side;  /*menu*/  }

.items{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap:20px;
  grid-row-gap:20px;
  grid-template-areas: "a-side b-side c-side"
                       "a-side d-side e-side"
                       "f-side f-side f-side";

}

@media (max-width:1024px){
    .items{
        grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-areas: "a-side c-side c-side"
                             "a-side b-side e-side"
                             "f-side f-side d-side";
    }    
}
```

```html
    <div class="items">
        <div class="item-a">logo</div>
        <div class="item-b">city</div>
        <div class="item-c">phone</div>
        <div class="item-d">search to site</div>
        <div class="item-e">basket</div>
        <div class="item-f">main menu</div>
      </div>
```